# URL structure for opening conversation in OWA outlook

Tags: url, outlook-web-app

I'm trying to link to specific conversations in the Outlook Web Application. So the idea is that the user clicks the link and the OWA opens with a specific email conversation (provided the user has access off course).

In [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/03e691c7-ad25-4628-a473-487c30c08d54/url-parameter-documentation-for-webclientreadformquerystring-for-exchange-and-owa-2013?forum=os_exchangeprotocols) answer, a way to link to specific email messages using ItemID is described. The url structure is as follows:

`https://your.domain/owa/#ItemID=<ItemID>`

This already works, great. I would like to change it so that a conversation will be opened using ConversationID. I've randomly tried the following:

- `https://your.domain/owa/#ConvID=<ConversationID>`
- `https://your.domain/owa/#ConversationID=<ConversationID>`

But it doesn't work. I know something like this is possible in the *older version* of OWA you could use the following:

`https://your.domain/owa/deeplink/readconv/<ConversationID>`

Is there something similar for the most recent version of OWA? Is there ***any*** official documentation available besides obscure forums?

Answer (score 4):

I think I've figured this out by intercepting the URL that Outlook 365 uses to open conversations in popup windows.

For Outlook 365, I have found this currently works: `https://outlook.office.com/mail/deeplink/readconv/<convID>?version=2020081704.13&popoutv2=1`

`ConvID` needs to be URL encoded, specifically the `=` at the end needs to be encoded to `%3D`. I am concerned that the URL format might change because of the version number in the URL.

For your case, maybe replacing `https://outlook.office.com/mail/` with `https://your.domain/owa/` might work? If not, I can help you use the browser to capture the proper URL format.

If you try this, please report back!

Comment: You can remove both the version and popoutv2 query parameters and it will, just like with both those parameters present, show the most recent email in that conversation.