# How to open an email from OWA in a new tab with directly link automatically?

Tags: google-chrome, redirect, office365, deep-linking, outlook-web-app

Sometimes I leave a Chrome tab open on an email as a reminder of things to do for example. But when the tab is refreshed/reloaded by Chrome Desktop or when a entire closed Chrome window is reopened, Outlook Web App displays the inbox.

So, after opening an email in OWA, the url is like this:
`https://outlook.live.com/mail/0/inbox/id/<ItemID>`

But trying to open this url in another tab redirects to inbox here:
`https://outlook.live.com/mail/0/inbox/`

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

There some usefully info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58393822/url-structure-for-opening-conversation-in-owa-outlook), but unfortunately the url layout does not work anymore.

**WHAT DOES NOT WORK**

```
https://outlook.live.com/owa/#ItemID=<ItemID>
https://outlook.live.com/owa/#ItemID=<ItemID>&exvsurl=1
https://outlook.live.com/owa/#ItemID=<ItemID>&exvsurl=1&viewmodel=ReadMessageItem

https://outlook.live.com/owa/?ItemID=<ItemID>
https://outlook.live.com/owa/?ItemID=<ItemID>&exvsurl=1
```

**WHAT WORKS**

```
https://outlook.live.com/owa/?ItemID=<ItemID>&exvsurl=1&viewmodel=ReadMessageItem

https://outlook.live.com/mail/0/deeplink?ItemID=<ItemID>&exvsurl=1&viewmodel=ReadMessageItem
https://outlook.live.com/mail/0/deeplink?ItemID=<ItemID>&exvsurl=1
https://outlook.live.com/mail/0/deeplink?ItemID=<ItemID>
```

Note: mind the `%3D%3D` at the end of the `ItemID`, it must not be forgiven!

**Automating**

Add a bookmark with this as the url:

```
javascript:id=document.URL.split("/id/")%5B1%5D.split(encodeURIComponent("=="))%5B0%5D+encodeURIComponent("==");u=`https://outlook.live.com/mail/0/deeplink?ItemID=${id}`;window.open(u)
```

or

```
javascript:id=document.URL.split("/id/")%5B1%5D.split(encodeURIComponent("=="))%5B0%5D+encodeURIComponent("==");u=`https://outlook.live.com/owa/?ItemID=${id}&exvsurl=1&viewmodel=ReadMessageItem`;window.open(u)
```

Now, open the email normally from OWA, then click the bookmarklet, it will open the email in a new tab from its deeplink.

Note: untested with other browsers than Chrome Desktop.

Comment: Question on iOS (unsolved yet), here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60339181/open-link-to-specific-email-message-directly-in-outlook-for-ios-uri-scheme-de